# usb wifi TL-WN725N_WN723N not working + problem in network setting

Tags: wifi

[image]
hi guys,
i am on elementary OS Loki, updated to latest.
currently my wifi is not working as in ubuntu and the wifi tab in network setting shows disabled even tho i have it clicked.
the wifi is working fine in ubuntu 16.04 tho.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal emulator and type this:

```
sudo nmcli radio wifi on
```

Answer (score 1):

The Realtek RTL8188EU chipset doesn't work out of the box in Linux Mint 18.x and Ubuntu 16.04.x. Also, it has an optical bug: the strength of available wireless networks is wrongly shown as 0 %.

For installing it, you can proceed like this:

a. First establish internet connection by other means, for example by ethernet cable.

b. Launch a terminal window.

c. Check the currently running driver for your wireless chipset:

`lsmod | grep 8188`

The outcome should show the name of the current driver: r8188eu.

d. Install the required build packages (the building tools with which you're going to build the driver):

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms git`

e. Download the driver packages by means of git, with this command:

`git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8188eu`

f. Now you're going to compile the required kernel module from the driver packages. Copy/paste this line into the terminal, in order to enter the folder with the driver packages:

`cd rtl8188eu`

And then run this command:

`make`

g. Install the compiled module with this command:

`sudo make install`

h. Reboot your computer.

i. Check the currently running driver for your wireless chipset: copy/paste the following command line into the terminal:

`lsmod | grep 8188`

The outcome should now show the name of the new driver: 8188eu.

j. Click on the icon of Network Manager in the system tray, in order to connect with your wireless network.

Note: do NOT install newer kernels, because then you'll probably lose the driver again!

[Give Credit Where It’s Due](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7#TOC-Realtek-RTL8188EU-chipset-0bda:8179-)