# Can't get my usb wifi adaptor working

Tags: wifi, usb

Well,I am getting problems with my usb wifi adapter (output by lsusb) Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter, [image: the output, what I get from network settings]

Here is an another guy having same problem... ( [usb wifi TL-WN725N_WN723N not working + problem in network setting](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6767/usb-wifi-tl-wn725n-wn723n-not-working-problem-in-network-setting)) I already installed bcom drivers without luck, waiting for a quick fix...

Greetings.... :D

Comment: Please edit to include results for `rfkill list all`

Comment: Rfkill listing not going to do anything... No errors there, actually no output , just a prompt $.

Comment: I enabled wifi through command line, by executing  " sudo nmcli radio wifi on " and included this command at rc.local to execute each time at startup. Bug found... GUI network Manager wifi switch not working properly, if I disabled it, it stuck at disabled mode, untill I renable it again  through cli.

Comment: I think I can submit a patch of this bug... How can I get the eOS source code ? Specially the network Manager part ?

Comment: `apt-get source` followed by the package name after enabling source code repositories

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the issue with the command line (in a terminal window):

```
sudo nmcli radio wifi on
```

Comment: the command - $ sudo nmcli radio wifi on
Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Wifi glitches can be fixed just by updating your linux kernel.

Comment: This is a pantheon specific bug with switchboard-plug-networking plugin, that I reported already a few months ago. https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-networking/issues/84

Comment: The same version of kernel works fine if I install GNOME or KDE desktop there in the same elementary distro.